I'm facing "One or more of Hosting's HTTP GET requests for the ACME challenge failed: 13.248.243.5: 404 Not Found, 76.223.105.230: 404 Not Found"
I'm trying to add a domain in firebase from godaddy, and getting this error while verifying.
Have tried to add those records and after deleted them as well as the firebase was asking to do. But error still remains the same.
Can anyone help to fix it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

wait from 2 to 8 hours to active your records
